# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.taxig10.demo.service.PersonaDetailsImpl' in your configuration. ERROR The injection point has the following anno

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm actually defining login with websecurity enabled, and i don't really know what is wring with my annotations that don't allow me to continue testing...
Here is the trace:

```
2021-10-29 13:58:09.436  INFO 10044 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-10-29 13:58:09.447  INFO 10044 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-10-29 13:58:09.447  INFO 10044 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
2021-10-29 13:58:09.534  INFO 10044 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-10-29 13:58:09.534  INFO 10044 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1188 ms
2021-10-29 13:58:09.682  INFO 10044 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-10-29 13:58:09.731  INFO 10044 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-10-29 13:58:09.845  INFO 10044 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-10-29 13:58:09.933  INFO 10044 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-10-29 13:58:10.065  INFO 10044 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-10-29 13:58:10.089  INFO 10044 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
2021-10-29 13:58:10.628  INFO 10044 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-10-29 13:58:10.636  INFO 10044 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-29 13:58:10.670  WARN 10044 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-10-29 13:58:10.687  WARN 10044 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personaDetails'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.taxig10.demo.service.PersonaDetailsImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2021-10-29 13:58:10.687  INFO 10044 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-29 13:58:10.689  INFO 10044 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-10-29 13:58:10.695  INFO 10044 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-10-29 13:58:10.696  INFO 10044 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-10-29 13:58:10.706  INFO 10044 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-10-29 13:58:10.720 ERROR 10044 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field personaDetails in com.taxig10.demo.config.WebSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.taxig10.demo.service.PersonaDetailsImpl' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.taxig10.demo.service.PersonaDetailsImpl' in your configuration.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**And my classes:**

***// app class***

```
package com.taxig10.demo;
        
        import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
        
        @SpringBootApplication
        public class TaxiG10Application {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(TaxiG10Application.class, args);
            }
        
        }
```

***// config class***

```
 package com.taxig10.demo.config;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
        import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
        
        import com.taxig10.demo.service.PersonaDetailsImpl;
        
        
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
            
            @Autowired
            private PersonaDetailsImpl personaDetails;
            
            @Bean
            public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
                return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            }
        
            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.userDetailsService(personaDetails).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            }
        
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/auth/**","public/**","/css/**","/js/**")
                    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/auth/index/").defaultSuccessUrl("/private/index",true).failureUrl("/auth/login?error=true")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login-post").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout().logoutUrl("/logout/").logoutSuccessUrl("public/index");
            }
        
        }
```

***// IPersona class***
package com.taxig10.demo.interfaces;

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.taxig10.demo.modelo.Persona;

@Repository
public interface Ipersona extends CrudRepository<Persona, Integer> {
    
}
```

***// IpersonaService class***
package com.taxig10.demo.interfaceService;

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import com.taxig10.demo.modelo.Persona;

public interface IpersonaService {
    public List<Persona> listar();
    public Optional<Persona> listarId(int id);
    public Persona save(Persona p) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException;
    public void delete(int id);
    boolean login(Persona persona);
    int confirm(Persona p);
    boolean isAdmin(String name);
    void logout(Persona persona);
    // ---
    public Persona getPersonaFromBD(String name);
    public Persona registrar(Persona p);
}
```

**// PersonaService class**
package com.taxig10.demo.service;

```
@Service
public class PersonaService implements IpersonaService {
    
    @Autowired
    private Ipersona data;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Override
    public List<Persona> listar() {
        return (List<Persona>)data.findAll();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Persona getPersonaFromBD(String name) {
        Iterator<Persona> personas = data.findAll().iterator();
        while(personas.hasNext()) {
            Persona cont = personas.next();
            if(cont.getName().equals(name)) {
                return cont;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

***// PersonaDetailsImpl class***

```
package com.taxig10.demo.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.taxig10.demo.interfaceService.IpersonaService;
import com.taxig10.demo.modelo.Persona;

public class PersonaDetailsImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    
    @Autowired
    private IpersonaService personaService;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Persona persona = personaService.getPersonaFromBD(name);
        UserBuilder builder = null;
        
        if(persona != null) {
            builder = User.withUsername(name);
            builder.disabled(false);
            builder.password(persona.getPwd());
            builder.authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario no encontrado");
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

***Thank you in advance <3***

Comment: Well ... the error message is very clear: You don't have a bean of type `PersonaDetailsImpl` in your application context. (You even didn't show the class ...)

Comment: Sorry i forgot that one class... But yes, it contains a Bean, here you are:)   (i edit the question right now)

Comment: Well ... your class `PersonaDetailsImpl` is just that ... a class, but not a bean! To make it a bean, you either need to have a `@Bean` annotated method in any configuration class that returns an instance of this class, or you need to annotate this class with (at least) `@Component`.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much! Love this community